# Will the GC dispose/deallocate the memory allocated in jni automatically on Android?

Tags: java, android, c, garbage-collection

I allocate the memory and new the ByteBuffer object in JNI as following:

```
uint8_t* pBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
// fill the pBuffer
jobject byteBufferInJni = (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, pBuffer, size);
```

Then pass the byteBufferFromJni to Java layer like this:

```
callback(byteBufferInJni);
```

In java layer, get the Object `byteBufferInJni`.

The question is:

If i dereference the `byteBufferInJni` in java, like this:

```
byteBufferInJni = null;
```

Will the `pBuffer` disposed/deallocated by GC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the JVM does not know that `malloc` was used and the memory should be deallocated with `free`. If the ByteBuffer was to call `free` automatically, the JVM would crash if the memory is statically allocated:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "Hello, World!";
    free(str); // Never do this!
}
```

It is your responsibility to free it. There are many methods to acquire memory and require very specific ways to deallocate it, e.g. `malloc/free`, `new/delete`, `new[]/delete[]`.

Comment: Thanks. I want to make ensure who is responsible for freeing. How about the object `byteBufferInJni ` by  NewDirectByteBuffer() ?

Comment: "All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references." ... "In most cases, the programmer should rely on the VM to free all local references after the native method returns." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#global_and_local_references

Comment: It's very helpful for me ! Thanks.